# IOS 7 - 2 digits phone number not working

Tags: ios, ios7, phone-number, phone-call, openurl

I'm actually trying to call 2 digits phone numbers via openURL (works properly for 3+ digits).

On IOS 6 i was using an hack, like this :

```
if (self.numberToCall.length < 3) {
    self.numberToCall = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?000", self.numberToCall];
}    

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://%@", self.numberToCall]]];
```

Not working on IOS 7 (does nothing).

Someone has a solution ?

Comment: Hey did you sort this? I'm having this issue now.

Comment: @AdamWaite how about tel:4-7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution :

```
tel://18;18
```

it woorks on iOS6 and iOS7

";" is used for phone context http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2806.txt

the phone number showed is 18;18 but it makes the call.

Comment: That works. Thanks. I can't mark correct because it's not my question but the bounty is yours.

Comment: Great find & congrats. Reading the RTC, I think the correct format would be something like this: `tel:18;phone-context=+2125551234`. With the context being used so that someone dialing from outside can still connect.

Answer (score 1):

You can try appending a pause, as in `tel:42p`, this will show as `42,`. Not great, but a workaround. It looks like Apple has been having a lot of issues with this because the behavior changes so often between iOS versions.

Comment: Telephony requires a pause command of some sort. It's a matter of finding what it maps to. It might be as simple as using a comma.